# Access token redirect not working

Tags: facebook, token

Hi hope someone can help,

For some reason when requesting access token via
    https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=**&redirect_uri=**&client_secret=**&code=**

The token is returned  as html output and not redirected to the specified redirect_uri location

However when I request authorization via
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=**&redirect_uri=**&scope=offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream,publish_actions,manage_pages

This work fine. Redirect occurs with code parameter.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one isn't somewhere you send users to, it's a URL you make a request to from your code to retrieve the access token, it's not supposed to redirect.

The purpose of the `redirect_uri` parameter there is to verify that you're the same app which called the auth dialog and received the `code` originally

You should check out the server side oauth docs if you haven't done so already: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/